# Why doesn't this SpriteKit program draw anything?

Tags: swift, macos, sprite-kit

The associated ViewController is the auto-generated default, and calls presentScene on a GameScene object.  I can demonstrate that the SKAction.run closure runs, but the SKLabelNode never appears.  Black screen.

BTW, for reasons pertaining to a much more complex project, we want to learn how to create an SKScene programmatically, not using a Nib.  This test project has no Nib.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var label : SKLabelNode?
    var mouseLife = 30

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        label = SKLabelNode(text: "30")
        label?.alpha = 1.0
        label?.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
        label?.fontSize = 10
        label?.color = NSColor.red
        scene?.addChild(label!)

        let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)
        let tick = SKAction.run {
            self.mouseLife = self.mouseLife - 1
            self.label!.text = String(self.mouseLife)
            print("tick action ran")
        }
        let action = SKAction.sequence([wait, tick])
        let forever = SKAction.repeatForever(action)
        label!.run(forever)
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is going to be your scene anchor point is (0.5,0.5) so your label is in the far top right corner

Comment: default anchorpoint for nib (SKSEditor) scenes are 0.5 0.5... what you made will have anchorpoint of .zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Fluidity, your comment was helpful to point me in the right direction, and cause the right experiments to be done.

In fact, the error was even worse than that: my GameScene instance was not being given a size on initialization, so it defaulted to a size of zero. In practice this meant the entire display was one logical pixel, which was either white or black depending on whether text happened to cover the (0, 0) point.

Once that problem was solved, we were quickly able to organize around an appropriate anchor point.